Azure Durable Functions (dotnet-isolated): Implement retry logic based on exception type
I have a durable functions application with retry logic, that depends on raised exception.
For example, if this is a transient exception (like service unavailability or so), the retry should be performed.
If this is a non-transient exception (invalid request, etc) the retry should NOT be performed.
This was working fine in in-process model:
internal class MyCustomRetryOptions : RetryOptions
{
    public DefaultRetryOptions() : base(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 10)
    {
        MaxNumberOfAttempts = 5;
        FirstRetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        MaxRetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        BackoffCoefficient = 2;

        Handle = ex =>
        {
            if (ex is TaskFailedException failure)
            {
                return = failure.IsTransient();
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
}

Now I am migrating my application to dotnet-isolated model and there is no more options to specify both parameters (MaxNumberOfAttempts, etc) and custom retry hanlder (to check if exception is transient one) within custom retry policy.
In Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask version 1.1.2 nuget package
the RetryPolicy method HandleAsync marked as obsolete
There are only two ways how to make retry policy custom:

From TaskOptions.FromRetryPolicy, that accepts RetryPolicy:

public RetryPolicy(
        int maxNumberOfAttempts,
        TimeSpan firstRetryInterval,
        double backoffCoefficient = 1.0,
        TimeSpan? maxRetryInterval = null,
        TimeSpan? retryTimeout = null)


From TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler that allows specifying exact behavior on error occurred, but does not allow to specify exact retry policy (like max number of attemps, etc)

TaskOptions retryOptions = TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler(retryContext =>
{
    // Don't retry anything that derives from ApplicationException
    if (retryContext.LastFailure.IsCausedBy<ApplicationException>())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Quit after N attempts
    return retryContext.LastAttemptNumber < 3;
});

I am looking for a way to combine both approaches in one: with specifying retry parameters
(like max number of attempts) and retry handler (with checking if error is transient one)
But when I receive an exception in the custom retry handler, I am not able to check what exact type of exception has occurred in retryContext.LastFailure:
{
    "ErrorType": "System.AggregateException",
    "ErrorMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:*****))",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   
        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   
        at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__6_0(Task`1 t) ....,
    "InnerFailure": null
}

Is there any way how to detect exact exception type from retryContext.LastFailure?
If not, is there any way how to write a custom retry policy that can have both

parameters as Max Number Of Attemps, Max Retry Interval, First Retry Interval, etc
retry handler that can make a decision if retry should be made based on exception type and properties


Maybe you can specify which error you want the retry to be triggered on?
To combine you can use the TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler to both select your handler and to create your options including your own interval inside, maximum retries etc.
TaskOptions options = TaskOptions.FromRetryHandler(retryContext => {
  // Create your retry interval (can multiply the seconds by the attempt-number to get an exponential interval.
  await retryContext.OrchestrationContext.CreateTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), retryContext.CancellationToken);

  var ex = retryContext.LastFailure;

  if (!ex.IsCausedBy<TheTypeYouWantToTriggerRetryOnException>())
  {
    return false;
  }

  // Retry if you havent reached the limit.
  return retryContext.LastAttemptNumber < maxNumberOfAttempts;
}

       

